# Change root of a "custom" tree with another node of the tree

Tags: java, recursion, tree, nodes

Basically what I have is a class Node, which contains an IP, it's parent node and a list of children:

```
public class Node implements Comparable<Node> {

    private final IP address;
    private List<Node> children;
    private Node parent;

    /**
     * @param address  IP-Address
     * @param children List of children this node has
     */

    public Node(IP address, List<Node> children) {
        this.address = address;
        this.children = children;
        if (!children.isEmpty()) {
            for (Node child : children) {
                child.parent = this;
            }
            Collections.sort(children);
        }
    }

    public void setChildren(List<Node> children) {
        this.children = children;
    }

    public List<Node> getChildren() {
        return children;
    }

    public IP getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public Node getParent() {
        return parent;
    }

    public void setParent(Node parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Node o) {
        return this.address.compareTo(o.address);
    }
}
```

So an tree structure can look like this: [Tree with 85 as root](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kCQIJ.png)
(the numbers are displaying the first octet of an IP as decimal)

And a tree with changed root looks like this: [Tree with changed root](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nbpvi.png)
note that i changed the prior root 85 with 39

Now where i need help is to finde a good and clean way to change the root and the parent/children of every node.

Right now my methode looks like this but it's very ugly:

```
public void changeRoot(IP newRoot, Node newParent) {
        Node node = getAsNode(newRoot);
        if (newParent == null) {
            changeRoot(node.getParent().getAddress(), node);
            node.getChildren().add(node.getParent());
            node.setParent(newParent);
        } else if (node.getParent() == null) {
            node.getChildren().remove(newParent);
            node.setParent(newParent);
        } else {
            changeRoot(node.getParent().getAddress(), node);
            node.getChildren().add(node.getParent());
            node.getChildren().remove(newParent);
            node.setParent(newParent);
        }
        if (node.getParent() == null) {
            network.remove(root);
            root = node;
            network.add(root);
        }
    }
```

And in the class network i am storing the current root node, a list of all nodes in this network snd a list the network which contains the root node and possible subnetworks.

```
public class Network extends AddressParser{

    List<Node> network = new ArrayList<>();
 
    SortedSet<Node> allNodes = new TreeSet<>();

    Node root;
}
```

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: What is `getAsNode`? I hope it is not scanning the whole tree to find an IP address...

Comment: Well basically it does, but i am storing every node in another list so i dont have to iterate through the tree.
But i already fixed this issue.

Comment: Yes, but it looks wrong to pass as argument `node.getParent().getAddress()` only to do `getAsNode(newRoot)` again in the recursive call. It is not your question, I know, but it would be nice to answer this question with a cleaner base to work from.